# Symfony2 form theming for individual field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am building forms using Symfony2 form builder and using `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig` theme (it is the default for all my forms), but I need to customize the layout for a specific field `content_owner`. It is a `multiple select`, so I am using the code below to override the default template:

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group">{{- block('form_widget_compound') -}}</div> </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and in new.html.twig (where the form renders):

```
{% for name, child in form.content if name != 'graphics' %}
                        {{ form_row(child) }}
                    {% endfor %}
{{ form_widget(form.content.content_owner) }}
```

The output I am getting (in firebug):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="form_content_content_owner" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Content owner</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
       <div class="form-group">
            <div id="form_content_content_owner">

             <!--and it is blank. no choice widget--> 
             </div>
                </div>
                   </div>
                      </div>
                          </div>
```

The code breaks all of my `choice widgets`,that is,no `select` is visible. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Desired output:**

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="form_content_content_owner" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Content owner</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
           <select class="form-control" name="form[content][content_owner]" id="form_content_content_owner">
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value="1">Anupam</option>
               <!--option value goes on-->
             <option value="31">World Com</option>
           </select>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the `choice_widget_collapsed` block is rendered inside a `form_widget_compound` block, so you've set up an infinite loop.

Try adding a debugger breakpoint into `Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer.php` at around line 250 just after where this code is:

```
$blockName = $blockNameHierarchy[$hierarchyLevel];
```

The look at what value `$blockName` takes during each iteration. Once you get to the field you are trying to render you should see which blocks are being called and in which order. This might help you understand what's happening in your templates a little better.

Comment: I would recommend this to anyone struggling with form theming in twig - as I have done on many occasions. Really helps with the understanding of this very complex api.